# my "if" statement returns false even if its true, why?

Tags: php, mysql

$status returns 0, but loop acts like its "1". Funny thing here is my error message is "MySQL DB is in use (status 0)".

In other words: my if statement fails even if its true.

Where is mistake?

```
include 'status_check.php'; //it takes $check from MySQL DB
if($status = "0") { //if status is 0 go on
    include 'status_1.php'; //set status to 1
            ...
    include 'status_0.php'; //after finished operation set status back to 0
} else { //if status is 1 say that its 1
    echo "MySQL DB is in use (status ". $status .")";
    die;
}
```

Comment: You are missing an equals sign.

Comment: `($status == "0") `  Equality, not assignment!

Comment: Use "equals" sign: `if($status == "0")`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're assigning, not comparing.

```
if($status = "0") {
```

Make that `==` for a comparison.

It's thus false because the string "0" is treated as a "falsy" value in PHP.
Docs: http://php.net/boolean#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: You should probably explain why `$status = "0"` evaluates to `false` as well.

Comment: if($status = '0') is false, because it's like saying if('0')